# Как получить содержимое (текст) сообщения Telegram зная его chat_id и message_id

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть message_id и chat_id
Какой метод мне нужно использовать чтоб получить текст этого сообщения?
В библиотеке ничего подобного не нашел. Метода getMessage походу не существует вовсе.
Пишу на PHP

Comment: не видел...но можешь пробежать по update'ам если их немного и там найти.... `https://api.telegram.org/botBOT_TOKEN/getUpdates`

Comment: Я смотрел, их там немного и ни один из них не подходит.
editMessageText
editMessageCaption
editMessageMedia
editMessageReplyMarkup
stopPoll
deleteMessage

Comment: это входящее или исходящее сообщение? если входящее то должно быть... вы все страницы пролестили и просмотрели прям? или только одну?.. там есть параметр offset и с его помощью можно листать апдейты

Comment: Это исходящее сообщение отправленное ботом (с админ правами) в чат. И после после этой отправки сохранился message_id и chat_id
Теперь мне нужно на PHP получить текст этого сообщения и запихнуть в переменную.

Comment: тогда увы и ах) сохранять нужно было)

Comment: Имеете ввиду текст сообщения в базу сохранять при отправке ботом?) Ну в принципе это идея)
Странно просто что нет метода получения текста сообщения) Спасибо за рекомендацию)